# Check DataGridView Cell Value (Alphabetic or Numeric)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

How to **check whether the value in the selected cell of data grid view is alphabetic or numeric ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Regex`

```
  var input = ...;//Your cell content 
  var patternAlphabetic = @"([a-zA-Z])+";
  var patternNumeric = @"([0-9])+";

  var regex = new Regex(patternAlphabetic);
  var match = regex.Match(input);
  if (match.Success) 
  {
       System.Console.WriteLine("Alphabetic");
  }

   .....
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you Itz.Irshad

Answer (score 2):

You can use The typeof operator Like the next code:

```
        if ( typeof (Int32) == dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.GetType())
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "DataGridView Cell Value is Numeric" );
        }
        else if (typeof(string) == dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.GetType())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DataGridView Cell Value is Alphabetic ");
        }
```

Comment: Well, DataGridViewTextBoxCell is by default of type Object. So, when we compare it on the basis of ValueType it didn't get the what we meant. But, Regex did it perfectly. Thanks for time.